# sort_values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I'm trying to sort the contents of my dataframe on 'percentage'. The sort doesn't seem to work.

Code-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zusp.png)

```
ipl_tot['Win Percent'] = ipl_tot['Matches Won']/ipl_tot['Matches 
Played'] * 100
ipl_tot.sort_values(by = (['Matches Won', 'Win Percent']),ascending = 
False)
ipl_tot
```

Comment: You need to either re-assign the dataframe or add the `inplace=True` parameter in `sort_values` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in the `inplace=True` parameter to `sort_values` function to perform the operation in place.

Replace:

```
ipl_tot.sort_values(by=(['Matches Won', 'Win Percent']), ascending=False)
```

**With:**

```
ipl_tot.sort_values(by=(['Matches Won', 'Win Percent']), ascending=False, inplace=True)
```